# Magento 2 : Need to perform clean cache programmatically after records save

Tags: magento2, cache, eav

In admin side, I want to clean "eav" cache type on records save. I added code in **afterSave()** function and function also call after save records. But, I think it's not working because, parent **afterSave()** action perform after my function execute.

My code :

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel/MyFile.php

```
/**
 * Action perform after save/duplicate records
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $customer
 * @return $this
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
protected function _afterSave(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $object) {
    $this->cacheManager->clean(['eav']);
    return parent::_afterSave($object);
}
```

**Note : After save records if I execute `php bin/magento c:c eav` Then, I received perfect output.**

How can I solve this point?

Anyhelp would be appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can you try this,**

```
<?php

    protected $cacheTypeList;
    protected $cacheFrontendPool;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
    ) {
        $this->cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        $this->cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
    }

    public function flushCache()
    {
        $_types = array_keys($this->cacheTypeList->getTypes()); //For all cache clean.

        foreach ($_types as $type) {
                $this->cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
        }
        foreach ($this->cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
            $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE :**

**For single cache clean :**

```
        $this->cacheTypeList->cleanType('eav'); // write cache tag name
        foreach ($this->cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
            $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
        }
```

Comment: Not working : It returns error : getBackend() undefined method.

Comment: it's working in my module

Comment: Thanks I forgot to add getBackend() in my code. It's working now.

Comment: @RohanHapani Thanks for the edit, good to know for single cache clean

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cacheTypeList = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface::class);
$cacheFrontendPool = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool::class);
$types = array(
    'config',
    'layout',
    'block_html',
    'collections',
    'reflection',
    'db_ddl',
    'eav',
    'config_integration',
    'config_integration_api',
    'full_page',
    'translate',
    'config_webservice'
    );
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
}
foreach ($cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
   $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
}
```

**Hope It helps**

Comment: What is $this->_cacheFrontendPool? It returns error.

Comment: i just updated the answer please try this

Comment: Not working. It returns error : getBackend() undefined method.

Comment: I just checked it and it's  working in my module

Comment: Thanks for effort +1 for that. But, Your answer using object Manger. So, I accept 2nd answer :) Thanks I forgot to add getBackend() in my code.